# APNS Stream Closed Exception

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, netty

I have a Push Notification Servis and I serve hundreds of applications to send notifications. But an application sometimes send notifications successfully but sometimes get stream closed exceptions. I dont understant why is happening.

Stack Trace;

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: Stream closed before write could take place
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:167)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$FlowState.cancel(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:481)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController$1.onStreamClosed(DefaultHttp2RemoteFlowController.java:105)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.notifyClosed(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:356)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.removeFromActiveStreams(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:1000)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$ActiveStreams.deactivate(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:956)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection$DefaultStream.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:512)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2Connection.close(DefaultHttp2Connection.java:152)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$BaseDecoder.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:209)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.channelInactive(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:417)
        at com.eatthepath.pushy.apns.ApnsClientHandler.channelInactive(ApnsClientHandler.java:514)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:81)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelInactive(IdleStateHandler.java:278)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:388)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:353)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1075)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:236)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1403)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:257)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:243)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:912)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:816)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

apns stream closed, solve problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.